# The same version of this code is already been built

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, heroku-cli

I am getting this error while deploying MERN website using heroku

-----> Build
Running heroku-postbuild

```
   > ecommerce@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild
   > NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false && npm install --prefix frontend && npm run build --prefix frontend
   
   
   added 2097 packages, and audited 2098 packages in 44s
   
   161 packages are looking for funding
     run `npm fund` for details
   
   39 vulnerabilities (2 moderate, 26 high, 11 critical)
   
   To address issues that do not require attention, run:
     npm audit fix
   
   To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
     npm audit fix --force
   
   Run `npm audit` for details.
   
   > frontend@0.1.0 build
   > react-scripts build
   
   Creating an optimized production build...
   Failed to compile.
   
   Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')
```

-----> Build failed

```
   We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
   
   If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
   https://help.heroku.com/
   
   Love,
   Heroku
```

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
!     Push failed

Comment: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')` appears to be the real issue. Your title doesn't match the errors shown.

Comment: yeah,how can I solve this issue of cannot read properties of undefines

Comment: Hard to say without your code; find where you use `includes` in it as a start.